# Invalid certificate in Opera

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, opera

I'm trying to click on link which opens another site, where I'm getting this 'Invalid certificate' popup. In previous versions of opera, it didn't appear. Is there anyway we can avoid it. I tried

```
OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions { Proxy = null };
options.AddArguments("opera.switches", "--disable-extensions");
options.AddArgument("--dns-prefetch-disable");
driver = new OperaDriver(path, options);
```

It didn't help. Here is the image [image]

Opera version - 40.0

At least can we send 'TAB' and 'Enter' to the browser directly using something like 'Actions'?